# StoreKit Unable To Resubscribe

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storekit, storekit2

I'm going a bit crazy trying to implement subscriptions into my app through StoreKit 2.

Everything generally works fine the first time, but after a subscription has expired, when I try and re-subscribe, I get inconsistent behavior. Sometimes it will work okay, though very slowly. Most of the time however, product.purchase() provides a .success, though does not actually resubscribe, and does not prompt the user with any "confirm subscription" screen. Then, when checking the Transactions, the code correctly returns nil, seeing as we haven't actually renewed the subscription.

Is this just Sandbox behavior? I'm worried about putting the code into production with this bizarre issue.

My full code is similar to this - https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/engineering/ios-in-app-subscription-tutorial-with-storekit-2-and-swift/

UPDATE: Perhaps it is just the Apple Sandbox servers being garbage - if I mash the button over and over, eventually the "confirm subscription" screen does come up?

Comment: I encountered a similar situation, the Sandbox subscription expired, then I attempt to subscribe again, it immediately return success but indeed it didn't resubscribe it, do you confirm it's just Sandbox behaviour? I'm worry to put this into production too

Comment: I just found there is a way to resubscribe in here: Settings > App Store > Sandbox Account > Manage > Subscription > Options, why this behaviour is not the same in SubscriptionStoreView?

Comment: @Amos did you figure this out? Does production work and is TestFlight just flakey?